# Nodejs api 404 not found error while accessing url paremter

Tags: node.js, rest, api

i am making a nodejs api in which i am fetching applicant all record from db. my api url is like this

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
enter code here
var ApplicantCtrl = require('./controllers/applicantController');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.Port || 8000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.get('api/applicant/:applicantId/getFullDetails',           
  ApplicantCtrl.getApplicantAllData);
app.listen(port, function() {
console.log('Server is running on port : ' + port);
 });
```

and applicantController.js code is here

```
var connection = require('./../config');
var helpers = require('../helpers/helper');


module.exports.getApplicantAllData = function(req , res) {
var id = req.params.applicantId;
console.log('in applicantallData');
helpers.getApplicantFullData(id)
    .then((data)=>{
        if(data == null){
            res.send({
                meta : {status : 400, message : 'There is some error with query'}
            });
        }
        else{
            res.send({
                meta : {status : 200, message : 'Success'},
                data : data
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        res.send({
            meta : {status : 500, message : 'Internal Server Error'}
        });
    });

  }
```

But the api response is like this

```
Cannot GET /api/applicant/23/getFullDetails 404
```

Can any one tell me what's wrong here? why api response is 404 found.?

Comment: If anyone looking for Nodejs API boilerplate with Expressjs and MongoDB. Try this: https://github.com/maitraysuthar/rest-api-nodejs-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a lot of the necessary code in the express application that sets up the routes for the server. I think that is what the "enter code here" section is for.

[Here is a quick tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) on setting up a very basic express server.

For the URL in your example, you will need a route something like:

```
router.get('/api/applicant/:id/getFullDetails', function(req, res) {
  // implementation here
});
```

Also, unrelated but to be more RESTFul, you may want to change the URL slightly to something like: `/api/applicants/:id/fullDetails`

Comment: I didn't mention the full code of my server.js file. i am updating my code. please see that updated post and guide me accordingly.

Comment: where is the part of the code you are mounting `ApplicantCtrl`? Is that part still missing? You should have something like what Mikelax mentioned. 

app.use('/api/applicant/:id/getFullDetails', ApplicantCtrl);

Comment: @J.D. i have mentioned my AppicantCtrl code in my post. and also ApplicantCtrl mounting code in first part of my post which is like this

     var ApplicantCtrl = require('./controllers/applicantController');

Comment: That's not mounting. thats just requiring a file. You have to bind somewhere the url and the function that will be executed for that url. And I don't see that anywhere. Thats what Mikelax was trying to point out. so try using Mikelax code and instead of router just use `app.get('/api/applicant/:id/getFullDetails', ApplicantCtrl)`

Comment: @J.D. i have updated the post. now see in my server.js file code. i forgot to mention in the post. but still the same issue.

Comment: @Fahad_SUbzwari I think you are just about there. I think your error is related to the route not starting with a slash.

The line should be:
`app.get('/api/applicant/:applicantId/getFullDetails', `

Comment: thanks @Fahad_SUbzwari, if you are happy with my answer and comments I would appreciate if you can accept it.